# Writing Json using Newtonsoft.json.JsonTextWriter

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest

I am writing a json using Newtonsoft.json.JsonTextWriter.
Here is my code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw);

jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Name");
jsonWriter.WriteValue("Allan");
```

And i am assuming that `sw` has the json format {"Name": "Allan"}. How can i get the written text in some string variable so that i can use this json data in my http request?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

My answer is now not relevant, since the code sample in the question has been edited to include these lines, left here for posterity, see comments for more info.

---

You will need to add the following to close the JSON elements properly:

```
jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
```

Then call the StringBuilder's ToString() method:

```
string strMyString = sb.ToString(); //JSONString
```

References:

[StringWriter Constructor (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hshta06.aspx) | [Reading and Writing JSON (NewtonKing.com)](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/)

Comment: string is removing the {} from the json.Actually i just want to check if my json is correct or not it is related to my previous question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978928/post-json-with-rest-api-using-webreuest-from-wp7

Comment: Have you got the jsonWriter.WriteStartObject(); as well?  If so, may need to expand the code sample in your question.

Comment: StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
           
              jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
              jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
               jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("Name");
               jsonWriter.WriteValue("Zeeshan");
              jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
                string output = sw.ToString();
                jsonWriter.Close();
                sw.Close();

Comment: A copy/paste of your new code puts the correct JSON into the "output" string.