# Saving file Json create from Code behind Windows Phone

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, json.net

I write a Json in code behind using dll called Newtonsoft.Json

here's my code:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder);
        JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);

        jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
        jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("name");
        jsonWriter.WriteRawValue(textboxNomeCompleto.Text);
        jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("user");
        jsonWriter.WriteValue(textboxEmail.Text);
        jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("password");
        jsonWriter.WriteValue(textboxSenha.Text);
        jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
```

How can I save the file created in SandBox using the IsolatedStoreFile???

Comment: try storing the object of the jsonWriter in the Isolated storage

Comment: see a similar solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980403/wiring-json-using-newtonsoft-json-jsontextwriter

Answer (score 0):

I have written a short code for your help. I hope this helps

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

using System.Threading;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
namespace jsontest
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder);
            JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);

            jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("name");
            jsonWriter.WriteRawValue("Test");
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("user");
            jsonWriter.WriteValue("T123");
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("password");
            jsonWriter.WriteValue("StackOverFlow123");
            jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
            stringWriter.Close();

            saveOnFile(stringWriter.ToString());
            readFromFile();
        }

        public void saveOnFile(string data)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile myFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
             StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Test.txt", FileMode.Create, myFile));
        sw.WriteLine(data); //Wrting to the file
        sw.Close();

        }
        public void readFromFile()
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile myFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            try
            {

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Test.txt", FileMode.Open, myFile));
                string rawData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                textBlock1.Text = rawData;//use raw data as string of JSON data
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

this is a working code, rawData need to be parse first and then used as JSON object